# Elastic search return list from groovy script

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, groovy, nested, return

I am new to elastic search groovy scripting. Basically I have to sort all elements of nested of nested docs along with

```
"header":[{
       "id":6
        "sub-header": [{"val":0.07,"name":"a"},{"val":0.06,"name":"b"}..]
         },
         {"id":7
        "sub-header": [{"val":0.09,"name":"c"},{"val":0.10,"name":"d"}..]
         },
         .
         .
         }
```

I have a document structure as above where I have to sort on val desc with "id" field.

The output has to be

> Val:0.10, id:7
>
> Val:0.09, id:7
>
> val:0.07, id:6
>
> val:0.06, id:6

I used groovy scripting by defining a list, but I am not sure how to return a list from scripting to the elastic search output

Comment: can you please also post the query you have been trying?

Comment: the output you showed is your one documents, you want to sort the nested items for each documents, correct? please add more info if i am not getting your usecase

Comment: Yes. I want to sort the output based on the nested item of each document. This is the below query I tried.                                                 GET idx/type/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "val": {
 "script": 
   "def max=java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE;def list=[];for (t in _source.header){c=0;for(i in _source.header.sub-header){if (i.val[c] >  max){max=i.val;list.push(i.id);list.push(max);}}c++;}",
"lang": "groovy"
}
}
}

Comment: Thanks, will try to take a look